# How to turn OpenSSL::ASN1::ASN1Data into IP-address?

Tags: ruby, openssl, asn.1

I have an object, which pprints into:

```
   #<OpenSSL::ASN1::ASN1Data:0x0000000803ab37a8
    @infinite_length=false,
    @tag=7,
    @tag_class=:CONTEXT_SPECIFIC,
    @value="\x7F\x00\x00\x01">]>
```

It is easy enough to see, that the `@value` is an IP-address: 127.0.0.1. How do I reliably extract it, however -- so that it works regardless of endianness and other hard-to-test considerations?

I'm doing it the following way for now:

```
ip = v.value.split('').map {|octet| octet.ord }.join('.')
```

and it works on my machine, but I wonder, how reliable the method is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I report in a [related question](/questions/46494429/), I found an answer in Ruby's own code (`openssl/ssl.rb`). They deal with both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses thus -- using `unpack` instead of `split`-ing the string into characters:

```
        case v.value.size
        when 4
            ip = v.value.unpack('C*').join('.')
        when 16
            ip = v.value.unpack('n*').map { |o| sprintf("%X", o) }.join(':')
        else
            STDERR.print "The encountered IP-address is neither IPv4 nor IPv6\n"
            next
        end
```